# assign ip address to domain name

Tags: ubuntu, dns, vps, bind

I have Ubuntu 14.04 VPS with PHP, Apache and MySQL, also have 1 dedicated IP address and a register domain with following free Name server:

```
freedns1.registrar-servers.com
freedns2.registrar-servers.com
freedns3.registrar-servers.com
```

How can I point domain to the VPS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who have the same problem as I had, here it's my solution:

1. I registered to `namecheap.com` and assigned my domain(s) to its free DNS managemnet, after that set `A` record to `@` and my `ip` also `www` to my `ip`
2. set my domain nameserver to namecheap domain nameserver.
3. now you can visit your site with domain instead of ip